# How to get "Facebook Watch" vidéo suggestions from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to programmatically get the list of videos urls from the "Watch" section of the Facebook website using facebook's APIs?

How could I do that?

Answer (score -3):

You can click on share button and share it in your telegram and you can see video url link

Comment: Hi; I meant programmatically get the list of videos urls. :-)